# Is it possible to run a Kali 32-bit from USB in a 64-bit Windows system?

Tags: windows, kali-linux, live-usb, 64bit, 32bit

I have tried to run a 32-bit Kali from a USB in a 64-bit Windows 8.1 but I get an error saying that the boot failed (any more details).

I formated the USB device with FAT32, with an allocation unit size of 4096 bytes and then I used Universal USB Installer to burn the .iso image on the USB. Then, I set the BIOS to boot from the USB and disabled the Secure Boot.

I'm wondering if could the 32-bit version of the .iso be the cause of the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Get the "linux live usb creator" for windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried "Linux Live USB creator" as Michael D. suggested in a comment. But at first it didn´t work at boot.

**The solution for me was enable *Legacy Boot* mode in the BIOS, plus the settings I described in my question. This way it worked perfect.**

Even though, I think the solutions would work with another USB program (for instance, "Universal USB Creator"). The key was activating the option mentioned before.